# How to display text with proper text formatting under a collapse using html and jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I have designed a collapse with some input, but the text under collapse is displayed without proper spaces and line endings, please help. I want my code to be displayed just like the way i have pasted in my collapse(html code). I used jquery. Also help is much appreciated if someone can guide me how to input a text file to collapse instead of pasting all the input.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">FETCH LOCAL ADMINS OF SERVERS IN YOUR AD DOMAIN</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
<p>Import-Module activedirectory
Clear-Host
function Get-LocalAdminToCsv {
    Param(
            $Path          = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName,   
            $ComputerName  = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Server (Get-ADDomain).DNsroot -SearchBase $Path -Properties Enabled | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq "True"})
         )

    begin{
        [array]$Table = $null
        $Counter = 0
         }

    process
    {
    $Date       = Get-Date -Format MM_dd_yyyy_HH_mm_ss
    $FolderName = "LocalAdminsReport("+ $Date + ")"
    New-Item -Path ".\$FolderName" -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null

        foreach($Computer in $ComputerName)
        {
            try
            {
                $PC      = Get-ADComputer $Computer
                $Name    = $PC.Name
                $CountPC = @($ComputerName).count
            }

            catch
            {
                Write-Host "Cannot retrieve computer $Computer" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Red
                Add-Content -Path ".\$FolderName\ErrorLog.txt" "$Name"
                continue
            }

            finally
            {
                $Counter ++
            }

            Write-Progress -Activity "Connecting PC $Counter/$CountPC " -Status "Querying ($Name)" -PercentComplete (($Counter/$CountPC) * 100)

            try
            {
                $row = $null
                $members =[ADSI]"WinNT://$Name/Administrators"
                $members = @($members.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
                $members | foreach {
                            $User = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
                                    $row += $User
                                    $row += " ; "
                                    }
                write-host "Computer ($Name) has been queried and exported." -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor black 

                $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                                "Name"           = $Name
                                "LocalAdmins"    = $Row
                                                    }
                $Table += $obj
            }

            catch
            {
            Write-Host "Error accessing ($Name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Red
            Add-Content -Path ".\$FolderName\ErrorLog.txt" "$Name"
            }


        }
        try
        {
            $Table  | Sort Name | Select Name,LocalAdmins | Export-Csv -path ".\$FolderName\Report.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Warning $_
        }
    }

    end{}
   }</p>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I have attached the output.
[image]

Comment: you need to add line breaks and style the page to look how you want. It won take the style of your editor and paste it on your page

Comment: Wrap that code text in a `<pre>`

Comment: Thanks a lot @charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @charlietfl mentioned, you need to use `<pre>` tags.

> The pre tag defines preformatted text.
>
> Text in a pre element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">FETCH LOCAL ADMINS OF SERVERS IN YOUR AD DOMAIN</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">

<pre>
Import-Module activedirectory
Clear-Host
function Get-LocalAdminToCsv {
    Param(
            $Path          = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName,   
            $ComputerName  = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Server (Get-ADDomain).DNsroot -SearchBase $Path -Properties Enabled | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq "True"})
         )

    begin{
        [array]$Table = $null
        $Counter = 0
         }

    process
    {
    $Date       = Get-Date -Format MM_dd_yyyy_HH_mm_ss
    $FolderName = "LocalAdminsReport("+ $Date + ")"
    New-Item -Path ".\$FolderName" -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null

        foreach($Computer in $ComputerName)
        {
            try
            {
                $PC      = Get-ADComputer $Computer
                $Name    = $PC.Name
                $CountPC = @($ComputerName).count
            }

            catch
            {
                Write-Host "Cannot retrieve computer $Computer" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Red
                Add-Content -Path ".\$FolderName\ErrorLog.txt" "$Name"
                continue
            }

            finally
            {
                $Counter ++
            }

            Write-Progress -Activity "Connecting PC $Counter/$CountPC " -Status "Querying ($Name)" -PercentComplete (($Counter/$CountPC) * 100)

            try
            {
                $row = $null
                $members =[ADSI]"WinNT://$Name/Administrators"
                $members = @($members.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
                $members | foreach {
                            $User = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
                                    $row += $User
                                    $row += " ; "
                                    }
                write-host "Computer ($Name) has been queried and exported." -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor black 

                $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                                "Name"           = $Name
                                "LocalAdmins"    = $Row
                                                    }
                $Table += $obj
            }

            catch
            {
            Write-Host "Error accessing ($Name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Red
            Add-Content -Path ".\$FolderName\ErrorLog.txt" "$Name"
            }


        }
        try
        {
            $Table  | Sort Name | Select Name,LocalAdmins | Export-Csv -path ".\$FolderName\Report.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Warning $_
        }
    }

    end{}
   }
   </pre>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```